# Extract Schema from nested Json-String column in Pyspark

Tags: python, json, pyspark, databricks

Assuming I have the following table:

| body |
| --- |
| {"Day":1,"vals":[{"id":"1", "val":"3"}, {"id":"2", "val":"4"}]} |

My goal is to write down the schema in Pyspark for this nested json column. I've tried the following two things:

```
schema = StructType([
  StructField("Day", StringType()),
  StructField(
  "vals",
  StructType([
    StructType([
      StructField("id", StringType(), True),
      StructField("val", DoubleType(), True)
    ])
    StructType([
      StructField("id", StringType(), True),
      StructField("val", DoubleType(), True)
    ])
  ])
  )
])
```

Here I get the error that of

```
'StructType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Another approach was to declare the nested Arrays as ArrayType:

```
schema = StructType([
  StructField("Day", StringType()),
  StructField(
  "vals",
  ArrayType(
    ArrayType(
        StructField("id", StringType(), True),
        StructField("val", DoubleType(), True)
      , True)
    ArrayType(
        StructField("id", StringType(), True),
        StructField("val", DoubleType(), True)
      , True)
    , True)
  )
])
```

Here I get the following error:

```
takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Which propably comes from the array only taking the Sql type as an argument.

Can anybody tell me what their approach would be to create the schema, since I'm a super newbie to the whole topic..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the structure you are looking for:

```
Data = [
    (1, [("1","3"), ("2","4")])
  ]

schema = StructType([
        StructField('Day', IntegerType(), True),
        StructField('vals', ArrayType(StructType([
            StructField('id', StringType(), True),
            StructField('val', StringType(), True)
            ]),True))
         ])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=Data,schema=schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

This will get you the next output:

```
root
 |-- Day: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- vals: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val: string (nullable = true)

+---+----------------+
|Day|vals            |
+---+----------------+
|1  |[{1, 3}, {1, 3}]|
+---+----------------+
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I saw that I made a mistake when creating the example table. Both Structypes belong to the same Structfield "vals". I still didn't really find a solution for this..

Comment: My bad, I thought you were missing just the name for the second nested StructType. Check my new answer! Hope it helps